# My Image Correctly Displays when I View my HTML Document as a File on my Computer but not when I Publish the Site

Tags: html, css, image, adobe-brackets, broken-image

Code:

```
<div class="about-img">
      <img src="https://ella.sice.indiana.edu/~macnaust/headshot.jpg" class="img-fluid rounded b- 
      shadow-a" alt="image not found">
</div>
```

When I open this as a file in my browser, I see the image just fine. But when I navigate to the published [webpage](https://ella.sice.indiana.edu/%7Emacnaust/DevFolio/index.html), it is missing, and the alt text does not display either.

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: The actual URL in your web page is `https://ella.sice.indiana.edu/~macnaust/DevFolio/assets/img/headshot.JPG` which is 404 not found

Comment: Sorry, I am new to HTML and I am unsure what you mean. Is this what I should have for my image source instead of what I currently have?

Comment: That's what you currently have. The code in your page is `<img src="assets/img/headshot.JPG" class="img-fluid rounded b-shadow-a" alt="">`. Try changing it to `<img src="https://ella.sice.indiana.edu/~macnaust/headshot.jpg" class="img-fluid rounded b-shadow-a" alt="">`

Comment: So sorry to bother you -- I'm sure this is a very easy fix that I'm just not getting. When I open up brackets, the code that you have instructed me to change it to is what is displaying for me. What you have told me to change it to is the code that I already have that is not working for me. Not sure what I have done wrong.

Comment: Brackets is just a code editor -- like SublimeText!

Answer (score 0):

Try and remove the tilde and start over.  Actually tilde '~' represents home directory. When you place tilde in url, It will access from home directory.  So, put the picture in the macnaust/DevFolio/assets/img/ folder then change the src to

```
  <img src="https://ella.sice.indiana.edu/macnaust/headshot.jpg" class="img-fluid
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work, either. My university hosts our sites for us on "https://ella.sice.indiana.edu/~[insert username]", which is why I have that there. I can't imagine why this would show up correctly when I open the file in my browser, but not when I navigate to the live website...

Comment: https://ella.sice.indiana.edu/~macnaust/headshot.jpg is showing up just fine for me.  What is the url in the live website you say it is not showing up on?  I'll be able to tell you from the live site.

Comment: Thank you so much! The URL for the live site (which is failing to display the image) is https://ella.sice.indiana.edu/~macnaust/DevFolio/index.html. If you hit "About," you will see my name, profile, email, and phone. The image should be displaying to the left of that.

Comment: Here's how its compiling (how the server is seeing it) <img src="assets/img/headshot.JPG" class="img-fluid rounded b-shadow-a" alt="">  You need to find the /assets/img/ folder.

Comment: I see what you mean -- thank you for that. I was able to see this by viewing the source of my webpage. What is really strange to me is that I have gone in and changed that code multiple times and it shows that it has changed successfully in the file, but not the webpage. For some reason, the code on the live webpage refuses to update. I have also gone in and put the headshot image in the referenced folder and that doesn't work, either. Any clue on how to update this "stuck" code?

Comment: This very well could be caching.  Are you using any plugins for speed using caching--w3 total cache...?

Comment: I am not. Do you recommend that I install w3 total cache?

Comment: If you did it would explain why you see different code on the live site vs your local, thats all.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:  Change your code to below:  If it works, then google up on relative vs absolute folder path.

```
 <div class="about-img">
       <img src="/macnaust/headshot.jpg" class="img-fluid            rounded b- 
  shadow-a" alt="image not found">
 </div>
```

Comment: You'll want to learn the difference between these 2: <img src="/macnaust/headshot.jpg"> and <img src="macnaust/headshot.jpg">

Comment: Also, as a general rule its better to use relative path to an image, link... as an absolute path opens another connection to the server.